# Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

i was working on a shopping cart project and i want to add a product to the cart such when a user logs in and adds a random product to his cart it gets added along with his id
so here's my cart get and post code

```js
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user
    .populate('cart.items.productId')
    .execPopulate()
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user)
      const products = user.cart.items;
      res.render('shop/cart', {
        path: '/cart',
        pageTitle: 'Your Cart',
        products: products
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then(product => {
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.redirect('/cart')
    });
};
```

the code works when i click on add-to-cart button and i can see the changes in the database with increase in number of the quantity of products added to the cart along with the user and productid but then i get an error saying

```html
TypeError: D:\sessions\views\shop\cart.ejs:12
    10|                     <% products.forEach(p => { %>
    11|                         <li class="cart__item">
 >> 12|                             <h1><%= p.productId.title %></h1>
    13|                             <h2>Quantity: <%= p.quantity %></h2>
    14|                             <form action="/cart-delete-item" method="POST">
    15|                                 <input type="hidden" value="<%= p._id %>" name="productId">

Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

here's my cart view ejs code

```html
        <main>
            <% if (products.length > 0) { %>
                <ul class="cart__item-list">
                    <% products.forEach(p => { %>
                        <li class="cart__item">
                            <h1><%= p.productId.title %></h1>
                            <h2>Quantity: <%= p.quantity %></h2>
                            <form action="/cart-delete-item" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" value="<%= p._id %>" name="productId">
                                <button class="btn danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    <% }) %>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="centered">
                    <form action="/create-order" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Order Now!</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                
            <% } else { %>
                <h1>No Products in Cart!</h1>
            <% } %>
        </main>
```

and here is my app.js

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findById('5f79f8f231e4f319009071de')
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user)
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});


mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.lltqs.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
  )
  .then(result => {
    User.findOne().then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        const user = new User({
          name: 'Max',
          email: 'max@test.com',
          cart: {
            items: []
          }
        });
        user.save();
      }
    });
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong im really unable to figure out and a little guidance would be of great help
edit:here's how my mongoose models and addToCart function looks like
the addtocart function works but the only problem is the app throws an error

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  cart: {
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true
        },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
      }
    ]
  }
});

userSchema.methods.addToCart = function(product) {
  const cartProductIndex = this.cart.items.findIndex(cp => {
    return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString();
  });
  let newQuantity = 1;
  const updatedCartItems = [...this.cart.items];

  if (cartProductIndex >= 0) {
    newQuantity = this.cart.items[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1;
    updatedCartItems[cartProductIndex].quantity = newQuantity;
  } else {
    updatedCartItems.push({
      productId: product._id,
      quantity: newQuantity
    });
  }
  const updatedCart = {
    items: updatedCartItems
  };
  this.cart = updatedCart;
  return this.save();
};
```

Comment: is it wrong to add the productId in between p and title and p and _id? or is it something else???

Comment: What does your mongoose models look like and what does `addToCart` look like?

Comment: @Christian will update in a minute but the problem isnt with the code since im able to add the items to the cart since i can see the changes in the database but the problem is when i decide to write a code to show the items in the cart box i get an error

Comment: In your cart.ejs try and only output the p for each product to see it value it is returning before digging into the supposed object

Comment: I would recommend simplifying the model a bit. Since `cart` only have one property `items` you might as well drop it and instead have `cart: [{ product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: true }, quantity: { type: Number, required: true } }]` and then when populating: `...user.populate('cart.product').exec()...`
    .exec

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christian for trying to help it means a lot but turns out the problem is because the id number in findById was copied wrong so I had to put the right id number and it started working perfectly, silly me lol